# Hindi fonts showing as question marks.

Tags: vb.net

I have used hindi fonts in design page of asp.net. It works fine, but when I copied it in another folder the hindi fonts are showing as question marks. Solutions?

Comment: on your computer's file folder???or server side folder???

Answer (score 0):

That font needs to be copied into destination computer.

Comment: i have copied this page to another folder in same project, on server side. But some thing strange i have noticed, when copied this web page in visual studio, the fonts changed to ???? but when i copied same web page to another folder by browsing this folder in widows environment that was smooth without any change of fonts to ?????